# Many-to-many relationship modeling in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, modeling

I followed what is outlined [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html). Here is my code:

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import db


class Book(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()

class Author(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class BookAuthor(db.Model):
    book = db.ReferenceProperty(Book, required=True, collection_name='books')
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author, required=True, collection_name='authors')

b = Book(title="My Book")
a = Author(name="Author of My Book")

db.put([b, a])

ba = BookAuthor(book=b, author=a)
ba.put()

b.authors
a.books
```

and I get AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'authors'

Answer (score 2):

[ReferenceProperties](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty) add [query-objects](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html) as attributes to the referenced class.  So look carefully at your mappings:

```
class BookAuthor(db.Model):
    # This adds a query-object as an attribute named 'books' to Book entities.
    book = db.ReferenceProperty(Book, required=True, collection_name='books')
    # This adds a query-object as an attribute named 'authors' to Author entities.
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author, required=True, collection_name='authors')
```

In your code:

```
b = Book(title="My Book")
a = Author(name="Author of My Book")
```

So, `b` would have a `books` attribute, not `authors`.  And, `a` would have a `authors` attribute, not `books`.

If you change the collection names, your code should run.

```
class BookAuthor(db.Model):
    # This adds a query-object as an attribute named 'authors' to Book entities.
    book = db.ReferenceProperty(Book, required=True, collection_name='authors')
    # This adds a query-object as an attribute named 'books' to Author entities.
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author, required=True, collection_name='books')
```

Also, if `BookAuthor` does not have additional properties, make sure you look at the list-of-keys method outlined in the article you referenced.