# How to define the models with Multiple to Multiple relationship in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

I am writing a Google App Engine application which has a data model with multiple to multiple relationship. I think I am doing it wrong. My data model class definition is:

```
class Project(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.TextProperty()
    admin = db.ReferenceProperty(Appuser)
    website = db.LinkProperty()
    members = db.ListProperty(db.key, default=None)
    start_date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_add_now = True)

class Appuser(db.Model):
    user_id = db.UserProperty()
    fullname = db.StringProperty()
    website = db.LinkProperty()
    involved_projects = db.ListProperty(db.key, default=None)
    current_project = db.ReferenceProperty(Project)
```

Now whenever I try to run this I get an error stating `Appuser is not defined` in the file. It happens because the class `Appuser` is defined after `Project`. I couldn't change the order as class `Appuser` also has a ReferenceProperty to class `Project` I would get a not defined error for Project. Now how to implement this correctly.

Comment: SO's had a few questions on this before: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347671/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347671/) , and Nick explains 2 strategies on his blog: [a join table or a list of keys](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/10/Modeling-relationships-in-App-Engine).

Comment: Your title implies you're asking about many-many relationships, but the actual issue seems to be with a circular reference.

Comment: @Nick: To be frank, I didn't know there is something called circular reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix to the circular reference issue is to drop the referance_class when defining admin in `Project` (it is not required just a validation really).

```
class Project(db.Model):
    admin = db.ReferenceProperty()
```

It's not ideal, but should solve the issue.